# Locate "chrome.exe" with an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

After installing SeleniumBasic and running the following excel vba test macro:

```
Sub test2()
Dim driver As New WebDriver

driver.Start "Chrome"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
End Sub
```

I get a

> runtime error 13: "cannot find Chrome binary"

Where can I analyze and modify the search path?
I run Windows 10 and my chrome.exe is currently located at `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`.

In the existing posts I could not find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following answer which has high intersection with the question you posted:
[Excel VBA using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205408/excel-vba-using-selenium)

> Do you have the selenium chromium driver installed? That is required and it is
> different than the server and Visual library. This is the actual
> chrome binary that will launch and run. Download the [latest version](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
> and place it in path such that basic can access it. I believe the path is `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic`

Comment: My problem has been solved thanks to the link mentioned above by replacing an outdated chromedriver. Thanks a lot! :-)