# VBA scrape webpage table .error object or block not set

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, scrape

I just recently noticed that the VBA works well this Code 1 which is the the IE browser code. But when trying to run the more preferred faster Code 2 it keeps coming up the error object or block not set. Any help or a pointer the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here are both the codes.

CODE 1

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTableB()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1500").Clear

    Dim ig As Object
    Dim urlc As String
    urlc = "https://www.totalcorner.com/match/today"

    Set ig = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ig.Visible = True
    ig.navigate urlc
    Do While ig.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ig.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim tb As HTMLTable

    Set tb = ig.document.getElementById("content_container")
    'Set tb = ig.document.getElementsByClassName("main_content")


    Dim rowcounter As Integer
    Dim columncounter As Integer
    rowcounter = 4
    columncounter = 2
    Dim tro As HTMLTableRow
    Dim tdc As HTMLTableCell
    Dim thu

    Dim mys As Worksheet
    Set mys = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each tro In tb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
   'loop thru table header
    For Each thu In tro.getElementsByTagName("th")
    mys.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value = thu.textContent
    columncounter = columncounter + 1
    Next thu

    'loop thru table cells
    For Each tdc In tro.getElementsByTagName("td")
    mys.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value = tdc.textContent
    columncounter = columncounter + 1
    Next tdc
    columncounter = 1
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
    Next tro

    ig.Quit

End Sub
```

CODE 2

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTableNB()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1500").Clear


    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument         '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting  Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.totalcorner.com/match/today", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.getElementById("content_container")
    Dim td As Object, tr As Object, th As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each th In tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = th.innerText
        Next
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
            c = c + 1
        
       
       Debug.Print hTable.innerText
            
            
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I recently noticed that if you run Code 1 first which is the the IE browser code then run Code 2 after it then works with out error, still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`, only the initial html code is loaded. As most pages nowadays, the page is build mainly by JavaScript, but `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` has no Javascript engine that can execute the code to get the full page. If you look to `.responseText`, you will see that all the data is missing. Maybe using Selenium is an alternative

Comment: @  FunThomas,Hi thanks for the  imput like i said before that if you run Code 1 first which is the the IE browser code then run Code 2 after it then works with out error. maybe you could try it and you might come up with somthing ,thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

More a comment than an answer:

You should no longer use Internet Explorer. It's outdated, unsupported and unreliable.

As written already as comment: Using MSXML2.XMLHTTP will not load the full page as the original HTML of the page contains only some basic things. The real data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript and `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` doesn't have a JavaScript Engine in the background. I cannot explain why it gets the full page after you first loaded it via IE - maybe it accesses a cached version of it. I cannot test this as on none of my computers IE is available any more (for a reason).

If you honestly want to scrape a web page using VBA, you could dig into using Selenium, see for example [Excel VBA using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205408/excel-vba-using-selenium).

However, for the URL you provided (https://www.totalcorner.com/match/today), there is a much simpler way using PowerQuery. In Excel, go to to the Data ribbon, use "From Web" and enter the URL. Select "Table 0" and press "Load". Now you have the data in Excel and you can do whatever you like with the data.

[image]

To refresh the data, simply press "Refresh All" on the data ribbon. Or do this with VBA:

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    conn.refresh
Next
```

Comment: @ FunThomas or anyone willing to help .As for PowerQuery keep gettng  the "access is forbiden" so trying to mimic as a browser using headers and user agents but don't know how to go about that as yet .If you could  point out how u managed to it from your end that would be great .Thanks again.